How to extract the whole match and not just the captured group?
This formula will result in "am" or "pm".
=REGEXEXTRACT(a1,"\d+:\d\d (am|pm)")

How do I make it show everything and not just the captured group? I want it to behave like normal regex, which would show the whole match.

Put another set of parenthesis around the whole thing?

You can change the capture group into a non-capturing group:
=REGEXEXTRACT(a1,"\d+:\d\d (?:am|pm)")


You don't need a group, you can simplify the pattern by using a character class:
\d+:\d\d [ap]m

And perhaps use word boundaries to prevent a partial match
\b\d+:\d\d [ap]m\b


Right, we do not need a group, capturing or non-capturing. The note about the word boundaries is also important.
